# Mongoose session.abortTransaction is not rolling back the actions

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, transactions

Here I am building the rental REST API and I want to perform transaction but it not rolling back the changes ,and it not giving any error problem is only changes are not rolling back.

```js
const session = await startSession();
const { error } = validateRental(req.body);
if (error?.details[0].message)
    return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
const movie = await Movies.findById(req.body.movieID, null, {
    $session: session,
}); // here i am adding the session
const customer = await Customer.findById(req.body.customerID, null, {
    $session: session,
}); // same
if (!movie || !customer)
    return res.status(400).send("Please check the customer or Movie ID");

try {
    session.startTransaction();
    movie.numberOfStock--;
    customer.numberOfRental++;

    await movie.save();
    await customer.save();
    await session.commitTransaction();
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    await session.abortTransaction();
    res.status(500).send("Internal System error");
} finally {
    session.endSession();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending much time i got to know that my mongodb server is standalone , for write property we need to convert into Replica Set.

Follow the official  documentation

[Convert Standalone to a Replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set)

Main point you should first close your server

My OS is window so - **net stop mongob**

For ios you can find at out yourself